# How to place a text and a rectangle (with some text) in the same line in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkkgmkuc/1/embedded/result/) in which there are some text and rectangles having some text placed vertically.

`I am wondering how I can put a text and a rectangle (having some text) align in the same line and also at the center of a page,` something like [this](https://s29.postimg.org/8l84h5iw7/development_design_v1.png) where a text and a box(having some text) align in the same line at the center of a page.

I tried using `float: left, float: right, display: inline-block and display: block` in some classes but unfortunately it didn't work.

The HTML code for every job opening class is:

```
<div class="job-opening1">
     <p class="section1">Development & Design</p>
     <div class="rectangle">
         <p class="job-title">Web Designer</p>
         <p class="job-description">Qualifications Go here</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `float:right` for all `.rectangle` and `clear:both` for `.openings div`, something like this:

```css
/**** Openings Start *****/

.openings .headline-text:before {
border-top: 1px solid #1072B8;
display: block;
position: relative;
top: -25px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
content: "";
}

.openings .headline-text {
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
color: #1072B8;
padding-top: 60px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.openings .rectangle {
border-radius: 10px;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-right: 5px;
width: 250px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000;
background-color: white;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
position: relative;
float: right;
}
.section{
  float:left;
}
.openings .job-opening{
clear:both;
}


/**** Openings Finish *****/
```

```html
    <div class="openings">
        <p class="headline-text">Departments</p>
        <div class="job-opening">
            <p class="section">Development & Design</p>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p class="job-title">Web Designer</p>
                <p class="job-description">Qualifications Go here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="job-opening">
            <p class="section">Full Stack Developer</p>
            <div class="rectangle">

                <p class="job-title">Full Stack Developer</p>
                <p class="job-description">Qualifications Go here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="job-opening">
            <p class="section">Marketing Director</p>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p class="job-title">Marketing Director</p>
                <p class="job-description">Qualifications Go here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="job-opening">
            <p class="section">Marketing Analyst</p>
            <div class="rectangle">

                <p class="job-title">Marketing Analyst</p>
                <p class="job-description">Qualifications Go here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The text seems to be little bit up from the rectangle. I am wondering how I can put both of them in the same line or text aligned in the center of a rectangle. Do I need to make some changes in the html and css codes ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Flexbox, like this:

```
<div class="job-opening1" style="display:flex;">
            <p class="section1">Development & Design</p>
            <div class="rectangle">
                <p class="job-title">Web Designer</p>
                <p class="job-description">Qualifications Go here</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

It needs some styling but I think it does what you ask. Flexbox is pretty easy to use, if you want you can check this tutorial https://medium.freecodecamp.org/flexbox-in-10-minutes-7295497804ed

Edit:
I think this is more accurate, I copied the style settings from your fiddle and put some spacing:

```
<div class="job-opening1" style="display:flex;">
        <p class="section1" style="flex-grow:1">Development & Design</p>
        <div class="rectangle" style="flex-grow:1;    
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        width: 350px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
        position: relative;">
            <p class="job-title">Web Designer</p>
            <p class="job-description">Qualifications Go here</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your element containing the text just add the float css rule, so that the elements below are going to float on the side of the element set with the float rule

```
.section1{
  float:left;
}
```